# Common Spatial Pattern to find EEG channels

Tags: pattern-matching, signal-processing

I have a EEG channel dataset containing N channel signals for left and right hand imagined movement trials (`X`). I want to find out the those channels which contribute more towards distinguishing the two types of movements using Common Spatial Pattern.

I have found the projection matrix `W` (of size `NxN`), selected the first and last 2 columns of `W` (denoted as `W'`) and transformed the original trials (`X`) as `X' = W' x X`.

This is fine but I want to know the exact channels which are making the most contribution in differentiating the two classes. (like channel 3,4 or 5,6).

Is it possible ? If yes, how?

Answer (score 2):

This can be done, but may not be the ideal if looking at the contribution of electrodes.

With CSP (and any linear filter) the projection matrix W is [number-of-channels x number-of-projection] (or transposed depending on the calculation). Looking at the weights of projection(n) will show the contribution of each channel on that projector. However, looking at the filter in this way can be tricky to interpret (e.g. signals must be normalized before comparing across channels).

The best overview for CSP for EEG is:
Blankertz, B.; Tomioka, R.; Lemm, S.; Kawanabe, M.; Muller, K.-R., "Optimizing Spatial filters for Robust EEG Single-Trial Analysis," Signal Processing Magazine, IEEE , vol.25, no.1, pp.41,56, 2008

Comment: Thank you ! , the paper you give is  a wonderful one , it's explain clearly The CSP issues in BCI.